# VBA Sum Range in One Column Until Non Blank Row in Another Column

Tags: vba, excel

I have a worksheet with a list of transactions and a variable number of lines per transaction. And I'm using the code below to sum the line amounts by transaction.

Column A is the transaction header (blank cells between transactions)
Column H is the transaction line amounts
Column E is where I want the transaction total

So if column A <> "" then start adding column H until column A is <> "" again.

The code works perfectly except for the last transaction.  If it has more than two lines, it adds up only the first and last line amount.  And I can't figure out why.

Any ideas?

[Here's a screenshot of my workbook](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gHxL0.jpg)

```
Option Explicit
Option Base 1

Sub SumColumnH()

Dim dSum As Double
Dim li As Long
Dim lj As Long
Dim lN As Long
Dim alRowFormula() As Long
Dim rng As Range

'Clear column 5
    Intersect(Columns(5), Range(Rows(6), Rows(Rows.Count))).ClearContents

'Get row Index where to write formulas
    For Each rng In Intersect(Columns(1), Range(Rows(6), Rows(Rows.Count))) _
    .Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
        lN = lN + 1
        ReDim Preserve alRowFormula(lN)
        alRowFormula(lN) = rng.Row
    Next rng

'Sum rows
    For li = 1 To lN - 1
        dSum = 0
        For lj = alRowFormula(li) To alRowFormula(li + 1) - 1
            dSum = dSum + Cells(lj, 8).Value
        Next lj
        Cells(alRowFormula(li), 5).Value = dSum
    Next li

'Final sum row
    Cells(alRowFormula(lN), 5).Value = WorksheetFunction _
    .Sum(Cells(alRowFormula(lN), 8), Cells(alRowFormula(lN), 8).End(xlDown))

End Sub
```

Comment: not sure, but it looks like you keep resetting the sum back to 0 in the loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your final .Sum is just adding two cells: `Cells(alRowFormula(lN), 8)` and `Cells(alRowFormula(lN), 8).End(xlDown)`.

You actually want

```
Cells(alRowFormula(lN), 5).Value = WorksheetFunction _
.Sum(Range(Cells(alRowFormula(lN), 8), Cells(alRowFormula(lN), 8).End(xlDown)))
```

P.S. Your other values could also be calculated using the .Sum function by using the following code

```
'Sum rows
    For li = 1 To lN - 1
        Cells(alRowFormula(li), 5).Value = WorksheetFunction _
        .Sum(Range(Cells(alRowFormula(li), 8), Cells(alRowFormula(li + 1)-1, 8)))
    Next li
```

Comment: That worked!  Thanks so much for your help.  And BTW, what's the advantage with the different summing method you mentioned?  Is it just that it's cleaner to use the same method as the final summing line?

Comment: @phelbin - Personally I would use the way you originally had (although I probably would have dummied up one extra entry in alRowFormula which pointed to the row after the last row - thus avoiding separate processing for the last transaction header), but I just thought I would suggest the use of .Sum for the initial records so that your code would be "consistent".